# Android app save data

Tags: java, android

I recently started making android apps. The app I'm working on right now is a clicker game. I need the app to save the players money. Is there any way that i can do that without using mySQL?
Here's my MainActivity code.

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    int balance;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //Hide notification bar
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        //Click counter
        final TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.balance_text);
        assert text != null;
        text.setText("0");
        final ImageButton button = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.click_button);
        assert button != null;
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v){
                        balance++;
                        text.setText("" + balance);
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

Comment: MySQL isn't the only database. You didn't specify if you want to store the data locally in the app, or remotely online so other apps can access it

Comment: We aren't going to write your app for you, sorry. If you'd like to try SharedPreferences, please refer to [the training documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html)

Comment: Sqlite,Cloud,shared prefrences,write to local file, content provider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a great article called [Storage Options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html), take a look and pick an approach that fits your use case best. Probably `SharedPreferences` will be the most appropriate solution.

Comment: Could you please put SharedPreferences into my code?

Comment: I can't, I believe it's your job to write your code.

Comment: I did a lot of googleing and i still don't know how to do it, please help me out i really need it.

Comment: Check the link that I posted, it explains exactly "how to do it".

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.